# What is the maven repository protocol?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have been learning a lot about Maven lately and am very impressed. Where can I find information about communicating with, deploying to and retrieving from a repository in the same manner as Maven does? Is this done through some published protocol?

I have found information about OSGI (and OBR) but cannot tell if this is what I should be looking into.

I would like to do this in .net (for whatever reason). I do not mind looking through java source code if someone could point me to the correct component, but would much rather be pointed to the protocol specifications.

[EDIT] I see a lot of answers regarding HTTP. I would like to further clarify, I am not looking for the transfer protocol, I am looking for the API protocol. For example, the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) uses the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol to transfer messages. What is the access protocol for Maven?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it's just plain http with GET and POST.

Comment: I don't see how OSGi is related at all. In any case, note also that there are several projects that use Maven repos, like Gradle, Ivy, and so on.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but FYI we've had very good success in using Maven to build C# projects using Sonar's maven-dotnet-plugin (from codehaus.org). Just thought I'd throw that out there since you mentioned .NET and Maven.

Comment: Thank you Allan, I am working on my own build system. I really like the Maven structure so I want to use the POMs and maven repositories without committing to a full port of the system. My challenge is either to shell-out maven or port just enough to do the things I want. I am going with the latter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As khmarbaise already said the transfer protocol is in most cases http(s), but there are other protocols available, e.g. simple file access for local repositories, WebDAV, SCP, SFTP, and so on. A maven repository is more a special directory layout. There are servers like Nexus or Artifactory that offer additional functionality like proxying remote repositories or certain checks like authentication.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Taken from
http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/rtf/repository+layouts
Maven Repository Layout:
`[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]`

Example
`org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-ajp/7.0.2.v20100331/jetty-ajp-7.0.2.v20100331.jar`

Comment: In your answer, should I assume that "Maven Repository Layout" translates to a REST API? That is can I call GET http ://www.myrepo.com/my.org/myartifact/1.0/item.jar and get my artifact?

Comment: Yes, if you use a server like Artifactory, Nexus, or if you simply follow the layout and use a normal HTTP Server then it will work with simple GETs but the version is repeated in the file and the orgId is expanded `myrepo.com/my/org/myartifact/1.0/myartifact-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 5):

The usual protocol is http furthermore for .net there exists already a solution which is called [nuget](http://nuget.org/) which supports that already and works with some of the repository managers like neuxs and artifactory.

Ah...Maven uses it's own protocol. No SOAP etc. May be a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-wagon-providers.html) will help a little bit. And furthermore [this](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/).

*Update*
You can simply download an artifact from a Maven repository by wget ...which is simply a http-get operation. To uplodate an artifact is simply a http-put ...you can do this by curl.

Comment: To be more exact, Nexus has support for exposing artefacts using a structure that Maven expects.

Comment: This answer is off topic. I asked about Maven, and you are telling me about Nuget. (down vote)

Comment: But you asked for **I would like to do this in .net (for whatever reason).** Hm..interesting...I just want to give a hint that things like this already exist.

Comment: That is correct. I am not asking about simply getting packages in any fashion. "**this**" refers to communicating through a Maven protocol.

Comment: `wagon` isn't really a protocol, in the sense it doesn't say what has to be transmitted over a network connection. It's just a unified API that ultimately implements the notion of "upload `$ARTEFACT` to repository `$URL`". It's more of a client-side specification that an artefact deployment protocol has to satisfy.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly, there is no special access protocol for Maven. Maven uses plain HTTP to get artifacts from repository. Repository should have special layout, i.e. URL structure (which simply projected to usual directory structure). You can organize your own repo simply by organizing directories in a special way: `[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]` without any special software on server side.

So, it is more about directory structure than special protocol. Very simple and working approach.

Of course, if you wanna additional services around it (like search, access control, stats etc) you should do it yourself. That's what [JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com) does with its [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) product.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't really a protocol. A Maven repository is just a specific resource structure available over HTTP (or in a local directory.) There's a somewhat dated [description available at Codehaus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Repository+Layout+-+Final).

"Deploying to" a repository means uploading the file in *whichever way you wish* as long as it's available to get from the above layout later. The [documentation for the `deploy` plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) provides examples for FTP and SSH, which implies a simple file upload into such a directory structure. But you might as well upload files to a custom web service that stores them in a database that is then appropriately exposed over HTTP. Maven won't really care; artefact deployment, storage, and repository access are decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET, with this format:

```
GET /content/repositories/approved-from-central/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.pom HTTP/1.1
Cache-control: no-cache
Cache-store: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Apache-Maven/3.3.9 (Java 1.8.0_102; Windows 7 6.1)
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I have documented it here http://www.javamonamour.org/2017/10/maven-to-repository-protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted "the protocol" is largely undocumented. It is mainly the folder structure which is documented. But it is a little unfair to say it is undocumented because the server-side is really nothing more than a pretty dump HTTP server.

The best official documentation is this:

https://maven.apache.org/repository/layout.html

For remote repositories, I think all other implementations than HTTP are nowadays so rare so that we can disregard them. The following is about the HTTP implementation.

- A Maven client must use HTTP `PUT` in order to upload content. (not `POST` !)
- I believe it is unclear if the server should support multi-file upload or not. And maybe it is irrelevant? I would guess that the default Maven client cannot make such assumption so it uploads files one-by-one. But I think it could parallelize its uploads without any issues.
- The client is responsible for maintaining the `maven-metadata.xml` file, but file residing on the server. For example, the [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) will (at the end of a batch upload) download the recent copy of this file from the server (if any), manipulate it and then upload it again. Maven consuming clients will make heavy use of this file in order to figure out what versions of an artifact are available. Btw, the maintenance of the `maven-metadata.xml` file is the reason why an uploader need not only `PUT` permission but even `GET` permission too.
- The [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) uploads the POM file *before* it uploads the actual artifacts. I would have implemented it as the *last thing* it does in order to have a 'signal' that an upload session is complete. With the current behavior I would imagine that the server might have 'orphans' (i.e. results of non-completed uploads). But one can imagine that a server-side implementation can use the `maven-metadata.xml` file to periodically perform orphan removal. Just guessing here.
- The server may optionally publish an index of all content in the repository. Some IDEs make use of this. It is documented in the above link.

So, as you can see, most of the logic is actually with the Maven client. The Maven server-side can pretty much accept uploads and service downloads without even knowing itself that it is indeed a Maven Repository server. It is pretty dumb. Only when it comes to the index (a feature the server doesn't have to support) will the server-side need to know something about Maven repo structure.